# Lookup value is a concatenate of row and column in a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, excel-2016, array-formulas

I have a workbook where the lookup value is a concatenate of the row and column of a table. I understand how to index match, but can't figure out how to make it match the lookup value to the correct concatenate.

[image]

I would need to take whatever the look up is, find the concatenate in the table and spit out the matching value. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try,

```
=index(b2:f6, match(--left(i3), a2:a6, 0), match(right(i3), b1:f1, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you! Made a few tweaks, but this works for what I need to do.